# How to search in a string within a given range?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have to search a String for a specific character, within a specified range. The code I made is as follows:

```
str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin()+5);
str.erase(str.begin() + 9, str.end()); // The range to be searched has been specified ie 5th index to 9th index
 if(  str.find('a') != string::npos){
       cout << "YES, it exists" << endl;
   }else{
       cout << "No, it doesnt" << endl;
   }
```

The above code works as expected, but I would love to know if there is a standard library function that would do this work.(Probably in one line)

Comment: You erase characters from the string. What do you mean with " // The range to be searched has been specified"?

Answer (score 5):

> ... but I would love to know if there is a standard library function that would do this work.(Probably in one line)

You can use [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to do this without changing the original string variable:

```
if(std::find(std::begin(str) + 5, std::end(str) - 9,'a') != std::end(str) - 9){
   cout << "YES, it exists" << endl;
}else{
   cout << "No, it doesnt" << endl;
}
```

Comment: The code works charmingly, but i would like to know if there is a better code (or STL) to do this.

Comment: @AdithyaDsilva Not that I'm aware of. What in particular you would like to improve?

Comment: I would like to know if there is some code like str.find(5, 9) where the value of the index is given i.e. start searching at index 5 and end searching at index 9

Comment: @AdithyaDsilva No, there is no such function available with `std::string`. Should be fairly easy to write an inline function that looks like `bool find_range(const std::string&, size_t start, size_t end,char)` though, to wrap what I've been putting in the `if()` statement.